GUI mostly freezes after unlocking desktop
Newbie here. I have 24.04 installed on a VM in VirtualBox on Windows 10. I've installed the Guest Additions and all of the updates for 24.04.
I'm having a problem when I walk away and the profile locks. I can unlock the system, but it appears to be mostly frozen. The mouse and keyboard work, but I can not switch between any applications that were open. The Dash only shows the Show apps icon. When I press on it, it does display the apps, but they do not launch.
The following are the important entries in the logs.
15:37:49 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dreport\x2don\x2dupgrade-247391.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
15:37:46 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
13:33:28 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-spice\x2dvdagent-142801.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
13:33:26 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
11:02:53 hpfax: [5959]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
11:01:13 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-spice\x2dvdagent-3677.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
11:01:11 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
11:00:52 (udev-worker): vboxuser: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxadd.rules:2 Only network interfaces can be renamed, ignoring NAME="vboxuser".
11:00:50 kernel: vmwgfx 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Please switch to a supported graphics device to avoid problems.
11:00:50 kernel: Invalid DMI field header.
11:00:50 kernel: RETBleed: WARNING: Spectre v2 mitigation leaves CPU vulnerable to RETBleed attacks, data leaks possible!

The only way I can recover is to log off and log back in, but I've lost all of my information.

Never mind.  After trying several things, the system will not start. It will not even get to the login screen. After pressing the  key, it shows the start-up commands scowling to a point where it counts through 10 procedures, then it keeps cycling back through. Since it is just a VM, I will start over. Thank you anyway.
